# Getting All Images from Firebase Storage

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-storage

I wanna get all my Firebase Storage images and display them. i did used ...ref().child("").listAll() method here and can get images paths in storage print them but don't know how to display them. please help me as soon as possible because my firebase test duration going to end tomorrow.

There is an important update on my work so I have edited it. I can get all of the storage images' downloadUrl one by one but just cant list them on screen.

```
import 'package:firebase_storage/firebase_storage.dart' as firebase_storage;
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class StorageAlbumDisplay extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() {
    return StorageAlbumDisplayState();
  }
}

class StorageAlbumDisplayState extends State<StorageAlbumDisplay> {
  String _text;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    getImages();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // TODO: implement build
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("ALBUM DİSPLAY PAGE"),
      ),
      body: Container(
        child: Column(
          children: [
            RaisedButton(
                child: Text("Get Images"),
                onPressed: () {
                  getImages();
                }),
            Flexible(
              child: GridView.builder(
                  shrinkWrap: true,
                  itemCount: 10,
                  gridDelegate: SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
                      crossAxisCount: 2),
                  itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                    return GridTile(
                      child: Center(child: Text(_text),),
                    );
                  }),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

   void getImages() async {
    final firebase_storage.ListResult result = await firebase_storage
        .FirebaseStorage.instance
        .ref()
        .child("deneme")
        .child("resimler")
        .listAll();
    //result.items.forEach((firebase_storage.Reference ref) {
      //debugPrint("found file: ${ref.name}");
    //});

    //debugPrint("resultın ilk elemanı adı: " + result.items[1].name.toString());

    await firebase_storage.FirebaseStorage.instance
        .ref()
        .child("deneme")
        .child("resimler")
        .child(result.items[1].name.toString())
        .getData();
    var url = await firebase_storage.FirebaseStorage.instance
        .ref()
        .child("deneme")
        .child("resimler")
        .child(result.items[1].name.toString())
        .getDownloadURL();

    debugPrint("ilk resim urli: " + url.toString());

    final _text= url.toString();
    setState(() {    });
    debugPrint("text: "+ _text);

    
  }

}
```

here is my console output and error that i get:

```
Performing hot reload...
Syncing files to device SNE LX1...

════════ Exception caught by widgets library ═══════════════════════════════════════════════════════
The following assertion was thrown building:
A non-null String must be provided to a Text widget.
'package:flutter/src/widgets/text.dart':
Failed assertion: line 370 pos 10: 'data != null'

When the exception was thrown, this was the stack: 
#2      new Text (package:flutter/src/widgets/text.dart:370:10)
#3      StorageAlbumDisplayState.build.<anonymous closure> (package:firebase/StorageAlbumDisplay.dart:43:44)
#4      SliverChildBuilderDelegate.build (package:flutter/src/widgets/sliver.dart:449:22)
#5      SliverMultiBoxAdaptorElement._build (package:flutter/src/widgets/sliver.dart:1130:28)
#6      SliverMultiBoxAdaptorElement.performRebuild.processElement (package:flutter/src/widgets/sliver.dart:1076:66)
...
════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════

════════ Exception caught by widgets library ═══════════════════════════════════════════════════════
A non-null String must be provided to a Text widget.
'package:flutter/src/widgets/text.dart':
Failed assertion: line 370 pos 10: 'data != null'
════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════

════════ Exception caught by widgets library ═══════════════════════════════════════════════════════
A non-null String must be provided to a Text widget.
'package:flutter/src/widgets/text.dart':
Failed assertion: line 370 pos 10: 'data != null'
════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════

════════ Exception caught by widgets library ═══════════════════════════════════════════════════════
A non-null String must be provided to a Text widget.
'package:flutter/src/widgets/text.dart':
Failed assertion: line 370 pos 10: 'data != null'
════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════

════════ Exception caught by widgets library ═══════════════════════════════════════════════════════
A non-null String must be provided to a Text widget.
'package:flutter/src/widgets/text.dart':
Failed assertion: line 370 pos 10: 'data != null'
════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════

════════ Exception caught by widgets library ═══════════════════════════════════════════════════════
A non-null String must be provided to a Text widget.
'package:flutter/src/widgets/text.dart':
Failed assertion: line 370 pos 10: 'data != null'
════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════

════════ Exception caught by widgets library ═══════════════════════════════════════════════════════
A non-null String must be provided to a Text widget.
'package:flutter/src/widgets/text.dart':
Failed assertion: line 370 pos 10: 'data != null'
════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════

════════ Exception caught by widgets library ═══════════════════════════════════════════════════════
A non-null String must be provided to a Text widget.
'package:flutter/src/widgets/text.dart':
Failed assertion: line 370 pos 10: 'data != null'
════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════

════════ Exception caught by widgets library ═══════════════════════════════════════════════════════
A non-null String must be provided to a Text widget.
'package:flutter/src/widgets/text.dart':
Failed assertion: line 370 pos 10: 'data != null'
════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════

════════ Exception caught by widgets library ═══════════════════════════════════════════════════════
A non-null String must be provided to a Text widget.
'package:flutter/src/widgets/text.dart':
Failed assertion: line 370 pos 10: 'data != null'
════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
Reloaded 7 of 663 libraries in 2.441ms.
W/meb.firebase(24891): Accessing hidden method Lsun/misc/Unsafe;->getInt(Ljava/lang/Object;J)I (greylist, linking, allowed)
W/meb.firebase(24891): Accessing hidden method Lsun/misc/Unsafe;->putObject(Ljava/lang/Object;JLjava/lang/Object;)V (greylist, linking, allowed)
W/meb.firebase(24891): Accessing hidden method Lsun/misc/Unsafe;->putLong(Ljava/lang/Object;JJ)V (greylist, linking, allowed)
W/meb.firebase(24891): Accessing hidden method Lsun/misc/Unsafe;->getInt(Ljava/lang/Object;J)I (greylist, linking, allowed)
```

Here is my console output after i push Get Images button, you can see the images' url as :

```
W/meb.firebase(24891): Accessing hidden method Lsun/misc/Unsafe;->getInt(Ljava/lang/Object;J)I (greylist, linking, allowed)
W/meb.firebase(24891): Accessing hidden method Lsun/misc/Unsafe;->putObject(Ljava/lang/Object;JLjava/lang/Object;)V (greylist, linking, allowed)
W/meb.firebase(24891): Accessing hidden method Lsun/misc/Unsafe;->putLong(Ljava/lang/Object;JJ)V (greylist, linking, allowed)
V/AudioManager(24891): querySoundEffectsEnabled...
I/flutter (24891): the pic url: https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/kalfa-firebase-projem.appspot.com/o/deneme%2Fresimler%2Fisim1608375656296?alt=media&token=b0ce2662-b668-4832-af20-0e9a20cf5446
I/flutter (24891): text: https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/kalfa-firebase-projem.appspot.com/o/deneme%2Fresimler%2Fisim1608375656296?alt=media&token=b0ce2662-b668-4832-af20-0e9a20cf5446

════════ Exception caught by widgets library ═══════════════════════════════════════════════════════
The following assertion was thrown building:
A non-null String must be provided to a Text widget.
'package:flutter/src/widgets/text.dart':
Failed assertion: line 370 pos 10: 'data != null'

When the exception was thrown, this was the stack: 
#2      new Text (package:flutter/src/widgets/text.dart:370:10)
#3      StorageAlbumDisplayState.build.<anonymous closure> (package:firebase/StorageAlbumDisplay.dart:43:44)
#4      SliverChildBuilderDelegate.build (package:flutter/src/widgets/sliver.dart:449:22)
#5      SliverMultiBoxAdaptorElement._build (package:flutter/src/widgets/sliver.dart:1130:28)
#6      SliverMultiBoxAdaptorElement.performRebuild.processElement (package:flutter/src/widgets/sliver.dart:1076:66)
...
════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════

════════ Exception caught by widgets library ═══════════════════════════════════════════════════════
A non-null String must be provided to a Text widget.
'package:flutter/src/widgets/text.dart':
Failed assertion: line 370 pos 10: 'data != null'
════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════

════════ Exception caught by widgets library ═══════════════════════════════════════════════════════
A non-null String must be provided to a Text widget.
'package:flutter/src/widgets/text.dart':
Failed assertion: line 370 pos 10: 'data != null'
════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════

════════ Exception caught by widgets library ═══════════════════════════════════════════════════════
A non-null String must be provided to a Text widget.
'package:flutter/src/widgets/text.dart':
Failed assertion: line 370 pos 10: 'data != null'
════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════

════════ Exception caught by widgets library ═══════════════════════════════════════════════════════
A non-null String must be provided to a Text widget.
'package:flutter/src/widgets/text.dart':
Failed assertion: line 370 pos 10: 'data != null'
════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════

════════ Exception caught by widgets library ═══════════════════════════════════════════════════════
A non-null String must be provided to a Text widget.
'package:flutter/src/widgets/text.dart':
Failed assertion: line 370 pos 10: 'data != null'
════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════

════════ Exception caught by widgets library ═══════════════════════════════════════════════════════
A non-null String must be provided to a Text widget.
'package:flutter/src/widgets/text.dart':
Failed assertion: line 370 pos 10: 'data != null'
════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════

════════ Exception caught by widgets library ═══════════════════════════════════════════════════════
A non-null String must be provided to a Text widget.
'package:flutter/src/widgets/text.dart':
Failed assertion: line 370 pos 10: 'data != null'
════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════

════════ Exception caught by widgets library ═══════════════════════════════════════════════════════
A non-null String must be provided to a Text widget.
'package:flutter/src/widgets/text.dart':
Failed assertion: line 370 pos 10: 'data != null'
════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════

════════ Exception caught by widgets library ═══════════════════════════════════════════════════════
A non-null String must be provided to a Text widget.
'package:flutter/src/widgets/text.dart':
Failed assertion: line 370 pos 10: 'data != null'
════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
```

Comment: You have to get download url of images while uploading and save that as well in the database to use further.

Comment: Do As @asifali said for getting the URL for images, and then to show the image use the `Image.network("urlofimage")` in your _code_.

Comment: there is someone in youtube who did this without using downloadUrl. he didnt use listAll() method but that can be an example what i want. he coded ...`child("imageFileName_i").getData(maxSize).then(data){imageFile = data;}` and imageFile is Uint8list variant here. after that he put imageFile in `Image.memory(ImageFile, fit: Boxfit.cover)` and image.memory is also in gridDelegate. he did sth like this. i dont know if we can share youtube link here so video's name is Creating Image Grid Using Firebase Storage. you can search if you want. In fact i can use downUrl if i can get all images's urls.

Comment: how can i get all images' downloadUrl as a list? i have to get all images' as a list downUrls to display them in a grid view dont i?  so i can put them in GridTile in GridView.

Answer (score 0):

finally i solved my issue just getting a simple error that i cant find out why. as @asifali and @mukul said i cant do it without getDowloadUrl. After i get storage's images names and getDownloadUrls with `...listAll().then(...)...`, i do put them in my `FirebaseFirestore` collection and get all images with `Image.network("urlOfImages")`. here is my solution codes, console outputs and errors that i get. i will be so glad if you help me about this new error.

```
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:firebase_storage/firebase_storage.dart' as firebase_storage;

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class StorageAlbumDisplay extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() {
    return StorageAlbumDisplayState();
  }
}

class StorageAlbumDisplayState extends State<StorageAlbumDisplay> {


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // TODO: implement build
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("ALBUM DİSPLAY PAGE"),
      ),
      body: StreamBuilder(
          stream: FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection("storage_images").snapshots(),
          builder: (context, snapshot) {
            final querySnapshot = snapshot.data;
            return Container(
              child: Column(
                children: [
                  RaisedButton(
                      child: Text("Get Images"),
                      onPressed: () {
                        getImages();
                      }),
                  Flexible(
                    child: GridView.builder(
                        shrinkWrap: true,
                        itemCount: 10,
                        gridDelegate: SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
                            crossAxisCount: 2),
                        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                          final map = querySnapshot.docs[index].data();
                          return GridTile(
                            child: Image.network(map["url"]),
                          );
                        }),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            );
          }
      ),
    );
  }

  void getImages() async {
    for(int i=0; i<10; i++){

      final _resultName  = await firebase_storage
          .FirebaseStorage.instance
          .ref()
          .child("deneme")
          .child("resimler")
          .listAll().then((value) => value.items[i].name);
      String resultName = _resultName.toString();
      debugPrint("resultın ${i+1}. elemanının adı: " + resultName);
      
      final _resultUrl  = await firebase_storage
        .FirebaseStorage.instance
        .ref()
        .child("deneme")
        .child("resimler")
        .listAll().then((value) => value.items[i].getDownloadURL());
      String resultUrl = _resultUrl.toString();
      debugPrint("resultın ${i+1}. elemanının urli: " + resultUrl);

      await FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection("storage_images").add({
        "name": resultName, "url": resultUrl
      });
    }


  }
}
```

console output and error:

```
Performing hot restart...
Syncing files to device SNE LX1...
Restarted application in 2.856ms.
W/meb.firebase(10713): Accessing hidden method Lsun/misc/Unsafe;->getLong(Ljava/lang/Object;J)J (greylist,core-platform-api, linking, allowed)
V/AudioManager(10713): querySoundEffectsEnabled...
W/DynamiteModule(10713): Local module descriptor class for providerinstaller not found.
D/ConnectivityManager(10713): requestNetwork and the calling app is: meb.firebase
I/DynamiteModule(10713): Considering local module providerinstaller:0 and remote module providerinstaller:0
W/ProviderInstaller(10713): Failed to load providerinstaller module: No acceptable module found. Local version is 0 and remote version is 0.
D/ConnectivityManager(10713): requestNetwork and the calling app is: meb.firebase
V/AudioManager(10713): querySoundEffectsEnabled...
W/meb.firebase(10713): Accessing hidden method Lsun/misc/Unsafe;->getObject(Ljava/lang/Object;J)Ljava/lang/Object; (greylist, linking, allowed)
W/meb.firebase(10713): Accessing hidden method Lsun/misc/Unsafe;->getObject(Ljava/lang/Object;J)Ljava/lang/Object; (greylist, linking, allowed)

════════ Exception caught by widgets library ═══════════════════════════════════════════════════════
The following NoSuchMethodError was thrown building StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(dirty, state: _StreamBuilderBaseState<QuerySnapshot, AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot>>#eb94f):
The getter 'size' was called on null.
Receiver: null
Tried calling: size

The relevant error-causing widget was: 
  StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot> file:///C:/ornekler/firebase/flutter_app/firebase/lib/StorageAlbumDisplay.dart:23:13
When the exception was thrown, this was the stack: 
#0      Object.noSuchMethod (dart:core-patch/object_patch.dart:51:5)
#1      StorageAlbumDisplayState.build.<anonymous closure> (package:firebase/StorageAlbumDisplay.dart:38:50)
#2      StreamBuilder.build (package:flutter/src/widgets/async.dart:525:81)
#3      _StreamBuilderBaseState.build (package:flutter/src/widgets/async.dart:129:48)
#4      StatefulElement.build (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4744:28)
...
════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
```

one more thing: if i want to do this with FutureBuilder instead of Streambuilder i getting a future error. if there is someone who do this with FutureBuilder i will be greatful also. thank you for your helps.